# Feature splitting when pasted into another shapefile

Tags: qgis, splitting, paste

Using QGIS I was trying to copy a 2 part feature into another shapefile as a single entity. I was able to create a single feature [image: Single feature]

the way I wanted it. I then attempted to copy and paste it into the ultimate destination layer but it then split/exploded into several separate features. [image: Split feature]

as can be seen by each one being labelled. The individual features are all separate in the attribute table. The other feature in the screen shot is as I expected to see the new feature.
I have repeatedly attempted various approaches but when the result is the same. I am sure I must have done this successfully before.
I have only recently started using 3.4.15-Madeira on Mac Catalina so the problem might lie there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the curse of the trainer applies to forums...... I solved it by selecting the errant features in the target layer and Merge. I had been attempting it the other way around.